# Set caret position in virtual space

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I want to set caret position in my visual studio extension to some location in virtual space.
This code do the job, but it adjust double value to nearest space position.

```
var newVirtualPos = _textView.Caret.ContainingTextViewLine.GetVirtualBufferPositionFromXCoordinate(pos);
_textView.Caret.MoveTo(newVirtualPos);
```

no matter pos = 0 or pos = 5 it will set caret position to 0, until pos become larger than space size... I want to set caret position to exact point on view... Is it possible to do?

Comment: What is your real scenario? :-)

Comment: I set first tab sizes using ITextParagraphPropertiesFactoryService, and want to adjust cursor position on the new virtual line... I don't want to turn off smart indention and don't want to add real tabs instead of virtual space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set the caret at an arbitrary location. Virtual space will always round to the nearest size-of-space.